# How can I draw GUI on a texture in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I draw GUI on a texture?
The idea is to use "render texture" of Unity Pro to which I would render the GUI and then I would apply it on a quad somewhere in space.

My problem is, that I do not know how to render GUI into the texture, since GUI is rendered on top of everything, not only in the camera.

Thanks!

Comment: Never really used unity but don't GUI elements automatically have orthographic projection? I'd imagine you'd need to render to a texture somehow. This post suggests you can do it with GUI elements. What kind of UI elements are you looking to render? http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/render-ui-to-texture.40641/

Answer (score -1):

You can use make a GUI button and give it a content in the content you can give it any texture you like.
Code can be found [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/542274/gui-button-with-both-texture-and-text.html)

Comment: The original question was how to render a GUI onto a texture. Your answer was the opposite. It shows how to render a texture onto a GUI.